# unable to install app after uninstalling it

Tags: android, android-studio

i am working on an app, the app installs fine first time then if i uninstall it from the phone after that the app wont install again until i change package name.

i have tried clearing cache of phone restarting it
when installing app using android studio it gives error like application installation failed installed failed conflicting provider

note that the first time app installs fine these issues are when i try to install it again or update it
and if i change the package name the app installs fine but then again i wont be able to update it

Comment: try to disable the Instant Run un the FIle > settings > Build, Execution, Development > Instant Run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install shows error in console: INSTALL FAILED CONFLICTING PROVIDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider)

Comment: i disabled instant run i doesn't work plus i am making apk and installing apk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing application and uninstalling does not remove completly - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095099/installing-application-and-uninstalling-does-not-remove-completly-android-stud)

Comment: @HananAhmad it might be helpful if you tell us what the actual error message is... because both of the "possible duplicates" may apply, whilst not knowing what that error message is.

Answer (score 1):

Except above recommendations, also there may be 2 possible reason for that.

1- Your device has another account (Guest account etc.) and your uninstallation not reflected to other account. You can try:

```
Settings -> Applications -> Find your application from list and Uninstall
```

2- If it is Play Protect Error

```
Open Google Play app -> Click Menu and choose Play Protect -> Try disable scan device and Improve harmful detection
```

Comment: if `1` would be the case, that would be `uninstall for all users` (see the linked answer above).

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too. 
I had solved it by **disabling instant run.**

> File > settings > Build, Execution, Development > Instant Run > disable instant run.

Try running your project again.

Comment: i would add to like another point there is always play protect error