# Issue with unsigned apk installation in some devices, "App Not Installed" error

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk

I distributed my android app apk to set of users through test fairy. It is not getting installed on some devices. It is showing "App not installed" error after trying to install.
I have set my minSdkversion to 21(Android 5.0-Lollipop) and targetSdkVersion to 28(Android 9.0-Pie) in my Gradle properties file.

**Devices on which I'm having issue in installing**

Nexus 6(android version 6.0)
One Plus 6T(android version 9.0)

**Devices on which I'm able to install .apk file without any issue**

Sony Xperia Z2(android version 6.0.1)
Google Pixel 2(android version 9.0)
Oppo Realme 1(android version 8.0)

I have tried uninstalling and installing multiple times.
I have tried clearing the package installer cache.
Gave permission to install apps from unknown sources.But no change.
Can someone tell me what should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you sharing your app with shareit or other app ?

Comment: No. I'm sharing my app using TestFairy(mobile testing platform).It will send you a mail to download the app/apk.

Comment: you can't  share the debug apk you have to build signed apk then you can share the apk

Comment: But I'm able to share it with some users and they are able to install it.

Comment: have you try clean and rebuild then create a build and share

Comment: Might be there is guest user too in your app. You need to check that first and if it is there then you have to _Uninstall app for all user_ instead of just uninstall app.

Comment: hey Piyush, can you be more clear? What is this guest user and how can I check that?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095099/installing-application-and-uninstalling-does-not-remove-completly-android-stud) you will get better.

Comment: Getting the same issue with Signed apk also@SandeepMalik.            I have tried that uninstall all users also but the issue didn't got resolved@Piyush. Now, I'm not able to install the signed apk in any device.